# Storing jwt token with Redux persist

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Can we store JWT token in redux state and persist it using redux-persist. Would it be a safe way to do?

Or use another alternative like store in cookies

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to consider the BFF pattern as described in this video:

[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)

The reasoning is that storing JWT tokens securely in the browser is impossible.